# Help to find the incubator library

Tags: eclipse, gwt, plugins, svg

I've just tried to import svg project with m2e but here I faced a strange problem as 
the pom.xml is missing gwt-incubator-slider.jar v 1.0 file ... As I can get it, the lib contains VSliderBar and HSliderBar . All I could find is this [link](http://www.vectomatic.org/gwt-incubator-slider) but I need a jar format :( 
For some reason maven cannot import the lib automatically so it makes some complicated thing here... I was trying to look it for with google but it gives just the src results :( So my question is where can I find the lib as a jar file?

Any useful comment is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The incubator library is deprecated and most of the classes have been migrated into the GWT mainline release.

Maybe this link will help: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gwt/gwt-incubator

Comment: Thank you. I've just downloaded it and checked but the jar package as gwt-incubator-2.0.1.jar\com\google\gwt\widgetideas\client\ doesn't contain HSliderBar or VSliderBar :( So it is not the lib I am looking for :(

Comment: I mean it is not the gwt-incubator-slider.jar v 1.0 Anyway thanks